# Extracting all values from the numpy.ndarray in python

Tags: python

I have a numpy.ndarray as a result below

```
[[0.13291089 0.02370989 0.00735158 ... 0.00724766 0.00437995 0.05021806]
 [0.12048984 0.02036897 0.01536853 ... 0.01494439 0.01646584 0.05641633]
 [0.22271137 0.10474296 0.10984567 ... 0.09325695 0.11456841 0.18628386]
 ...
 [0.8874626  0.70929044 0.6762439  ... 0.51335114 0.5903196  0.7918521 ]
 [0.5478848  0.22517046 0.19128235 ... 0.13549334 0.16085956 0.31617215]
 [0.28974912 0.05250879 0.02813596 ... 0.01802314 0.0206987  0.11103482]]
```

I would like to extract all the values from the above multidimensional array and store it into the one 1D array. e.g Array_a = [0.13291089  0.02370989  0.00735158  ...]  like this. How can I do this

Comment: numpy arrays have a `.flatten()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.flatten()` for this:

```
In [1]: arr
Out[1]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [2]: arr.flatten()
Out[2]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```